# jQuery ajax request MVC binding JSON inside JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm having a binding problem with my MVC site.

The following ajax request is sent:

```
var arguments = { 
    search: "test", 
    skipCount: 0, 
    range: 20, 
    filter: getFilter() 
};

$.ajax({
    url: "HTMLSearchResult",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: arguments,
    success: function (response) {
        //Showing search results.
    }
});
```

getFilter function:

```
function getFilter() {
    var filter = {},
        fromDate = $('#TodoSearchFilter_From').val(),
        toDate = $('#TodoSearchFilter_To').val();

    if (fromDate)
        filter.From = new Date(Date.parse(fromDate));
    else
        filter.From = null;
    if (toDate)
        filter.To = new Date(Date.parse(toDate));
    else
        filter.To = null;

    filter.Assigned = $('#TodoSearchFilter_Assigned').val() == 'true';
    filter.NotAssigned = $('#TodoSearchFilter_NotAssigned').val() == 'true';
    filter.Services = $('#TodoSearchFilter_Services').val() == 'true';
    filter.WorkOrders = $('#TodoSearchFilter_WorkOrders').val() == 'true';
    filter.Booked = $('#TodoSearchFilter_Booked').val() == 'true';
    filter.NotBooked = $('#TodoSearchFilter_NotBooked').val() == 'true';

    return filter;
}
```

The request is sent properly (controlled via Fiddler2) but the controller is unable to receive it correctly. "search", "skipCount" and "range" are populated correctly.

Here are prints of the console in the browser and the debugger in visual studio:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEPP6.png

Why is this binding not working?

I have tried using JSON.stringify aswell, without any success. I feel that since the first 3 arguments are sent correctly, so should the fourth.

Comment: You know you can host images directly in your post?  What exactly is the value of filter?  Ajax calls are made asynchronously, try waiting to send the request until you know that the value `filter` will be populated.

Comment: Are you sure the request expects a json body? did you try `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @user3334871 If I log the arguments with console.log(arguments) it's populated, as shown by the picture. So the getFilter() is executed before sending it to the server, as far as I know. I put the console.log(arguments) between "var arguments = " and "$.ajax({"

Comment: @Musa Using ´application/x-www-form-urlencoded´ yields the same result as before. search, skipCount and range get populated, but filter does not.

Comment: AJAX execute asynchronously, you cannot trust logging it to the console.  The second the command line reaches `$.ajax`, it will fire the request, regardless of whether your request is complete or not.  the console.log will execute in a timed order.  So even though the logging is before the AJAX call, you can't be certain it is executed in that order

Comment: @user3334871 I understand. But `getFilter()` is not an ajax call and should be executed when i declare `var arguments`. Is this not how it works?

Comment: @RobinDorbell actually, yeah.  I think I had my cases mixed up in my head.  Looking at what you are getting in the output, getFilter works, but it is not finished by the time you make an AJAX call.  So my answer just polls until it is finished.  If you get stuck in a loop, there might be something wrong with the function itself.

Comment: Does your ToDoSearchFilter has all the properties that matches the filter object of your json data? Since if does not match then there will be an issue in binding the data for that property.

Comment: @Venkat It does. But good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by only converting filter to a JSON string.

```
var arguments = {
    search: searchString,
    skipCount: skipCount,
    range: range,
    filter: JSON.stringify(getFilter())
};
```

Then while receiving it at the controller i used the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to create the object I needed.

Seems like a hack, but at least it's working properly now.